# Receive broadcast in MainActivity with non static inner class

Tags: java, android

I need to call certain non static methods in an activity when the user interacts with buttons in notification, I tried to do it in a standalone class the extends `BroadcastReceiver` it works, but I don't know how call a method on the activity mentioned earlier, I tried to make an inner class, non static, edited the manifest file it was first :

```
<receiver android:name=".Activity$NotificationBroadcast" >
    <intent-filter>
      .
      .
      .
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and that gives me an error saying :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 3189
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver 
com.example.app.Activity$NotificationBroadcast: 
java.lang.InstantiationException:
```

the class is :

```
public class NotificationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public  void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Activity.ACTION1)){
            // do things
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Activity.ACTION1)){
            // do things
        }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Activity.ACTION2)){
            // do things
        }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Activity.ACTION3)){
            // do things
        }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Activity.ACTION4)){
            // do things
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inner class cannot be instantiated without instantiating the top level class, your `MainActivity` - on this basis the error makes sense.

Comment: @MarkKeen please tell me what should I do, I'm still learning

Comment: It is difficult to provide context for a solution. If you have a notification it doesn't make sense that you are trying to call methods in an `Activity`  - what if the `Activity` is not open or visible? Also, why a static receiver? Do do you need the methods there, if state is not an issue can they be moved into a utils class and be static methods?

Comment: @MarkKeen the methods that I'm trying to call are not static.
is it possible when I receive a broadcast, to execute a method in Activity, cause I'm showing the notification when Activity is paused, and hide it when resumed or destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't make the receiver as an inner class, because when the receiver is statically instantiated, the "holder" class has to be instantiated as well. The activity instance is only created when it is meant to be active, and that's why you got the exception.

If you want the receiver to interact with the activity (by calling non-static methods in the activity class), I suggest that you should make the receiver a non-static one. This means that you need to register an instance of the receiver in `OnCreate()` and unregister it in `OnDestroy()`.

For a better design, the activity instance should be passed into the receiver via its constructor as an interface, so that the receiver does not get access to the whole activity object, but is only able to access the functionality.

Manifest should have:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationBroadcast" android:enabled="false" />
```

An interface for the interaction (IWorker.java for example):

```
public interface IWorker {
    public void doThis();
    public void doThat();
}
```

The receiver (a class on its own) takes the IWorker and does something when a broadcast is received:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final string ACTION1 = "com.yourpackage.action1";
    public static final string ACTION2 = "com.yourpackage.action2";

    private IWorker worker;

    public NotificationReceiver() {
    }

    public NotificationReceiver(IWorker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION1)) {
            worker.doThis();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION2)) {
            worker.doThat();
        }
    }
}
```

And the activity takes care of the receiver on its life cycle:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements IWorker {
    private NotificationReceiver receiver;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create the receiver
        receiver = new NotificationReceiver(this);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(NotificationReceiver.ACTION1);
        filter.addAction(NotificationReceiver.ACTION2);

        // register it
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }        

    @override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiver = null;
        }
    }

    @override
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("Doing this...");
    }

    @override
    public void doThat() {
        System.out.println("Doing that...");
    }
}
```

P.S. The above codes are for reference only, they're not tested and may not compile.

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated, it is working now, however it is givig me a RuntimeException for empty constructor for the NotificationReceiver clas, I did try catch to ignore the error, i don't know if it is going to have an effect or not, thank you so much anyway for your help

Comment: Oh it won't work if you just try/catch it. The above codes are just for reference and may not work right away as I typed them quickly on the fly.
I've updated my answer with an empty constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the best !!!
I know that, i didn't take the code as it is, I only took the idea, using an interface and override the methods it was clever from you, I tried to extend the Broadcaster class, but I remembered that an Activity can't do that, there where my mind stopped.